# Rails server is running on GCP VM instance, but unable to access the rails app on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ssh, google-cloud-platform, puma

I am using **rails 4.2, ruby 2.3, puma 3.4, nginx** and trying to deploy rails app on **GCP compute engine** instance. while i am starting the rails server on gcp instance through ssh, server starts running but on browser i am unable to access the app on any port. I have tried all the answers here but nothing helped.

*server log-*

```
$ rails s -b 0.0.0.0
Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
Please use a String or nil.
An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/home/sujeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4", "/home/sujeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/sujeet/furdo/log/development.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/sujeet/furdo/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
removed as of version 1.0.

You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.

Called from /home/sujeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  Spree::Taxonomy Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "spree_taxonomies".* FROM "spree_taxonomies" WHERE "spree_taxonomies"."name" = $1  ORDER BY spree_taxonomies.position, spree_taxonomies.created_at LIMIT 1  [["name", "Product Categories"]]
  Spree::Taxonomy Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_taxonomies".* FROM "spree_taxonomies" WHERE "spree_taxonomies"."name" = $1  ORDER BY spree_taxonomies.position, spree_taxonomies.created_at LIMIT 1  [["name", "Vendors"]]
  Spree::Taxonomy Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_taxonomies".* FROM "spree_taxonomies" WHERE "spree_taxonomies"."name" = $1  ORDER BY spree_taxonomies.position, spree_taxonomies.created_at LIMIT 1  [["name", "Package"]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "spree_taxons"."id" FROM "spree_taxons" WHERE "spree_taxons"."taxonomy_id" IS NULL AND ("spree_taxons"."parent_id" IS NOT NULL)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "spree_taxons"."id" FROM "spree_taxons" WHERE "spree_taxons"."taxonomy_id" IS NULL AND ("spree_taxons"."parent_id" IS NOT NULL)
  Spree::Property Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_properties".* FROM "spree_properties" WHERE "spree_properties"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "vendor_link"]]
  Spree::Property Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_properties".* FROM "spree_properties" WHERE "spree_properties"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "stock"]]
  Spree::Property Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_properties".* FROM "spree_properties" WHERE "spree_properties"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "3d_modeled"]]
  Spree::Property Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_properties".* FROM "spree_properties" WHERE "spree_properties"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "theme_designer"]]
  Spree::OptionType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_option_types".* FROM "spree_option_types" WHERE "spree_option_types"."name" = $1  ORDER BY spree_option_types.position LIMIT 1  [["name", "Focus"]]
  Spree::AuthenticationMethod Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "spree_authentication_methods".* FROM "spree_authentication_methods" WHERE "spree_authentication_methods"."environment" = $1  [["environment", "development"]]
  Spree::AuthenticationMethod Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_authentication_methods".* FROM "spree_authentication_methods" WHERE "spree_authentication_methods"."environment" = $1  [["environment", "development"]]
  Spree::AuthenticationMethod Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "spree_authentication_methods".* FROM "spree_authentication_methods" WHERE "spree_authentication_methods"."environment" = $1  [["environment", "development"]]
  Spree::AuthenticationMethod Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_authentication_methods".* FROM "spree_authentication_methods" WHERE "spree_authentication_methods"."environment" = $1  [["environment", "development"]]
  Spree::AuthenticationMethod Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_authentication_methods".* FROM "spree_authentication_methods" WHERE "spree_authentication_methods"."environment" = $1  [["environment", "development"]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: Devise.allow_insecure_token_lookup= is deprecated and has no effect. (called from allow_insecure_token_lookup= at (eval):6)
  Spree::Preference Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/auth_configuration/confirmable"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Preference Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/auth_configuration/confirmable' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  Spree::Preference Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/default_country_id"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Preference Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/default_country_id' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Spree::Preference Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/always_include_confirm_step"]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Preference Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/always_include_confirm_step' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Spree::Preference Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/check_for_spree_alerts"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Preference Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/check_for_spree_alerts' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 4) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Spree::Preference Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/social_configuration/path_prefix"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Preference Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/social_configuration/path_prefix' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 5) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
* Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1548153185501-23281
Use Ctrl-C to stop*
```

Comment: what about the firewall? do you have enable the traffic to the port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you are allowing the traffic trough the port your application is being published? Here's a doc to create a [Firewall Rule in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules), in the firewall rule you should add the port or ports that your application uses. Also make sure that your local firewall is not blocking the application.